# Querying values using OData and LINQ that contain '<' and '>' characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, encoding, odata

I have a server application that uses a SQL Server database and I am using OData to access it from a client application. I have an issue using LINQ queries to find matching records where columns have values that contain '<' and '>' characters.

For example, I have a table named Procedures with a column named cProcedureName and one record has the value "Test <missing> value" for cProcdureName. When I use the following query, I get an exception:

```
procedureName = "Test <missing> value";
var procs = dataContext.Procedures
   .Where(p => p.cProcedureName == procedureName).ToList();
```

Exception message (partial):

```
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client ($filter=&quot;...eName eq '&lt;Missing&gt; Version/IN...&quot;).
```

I have tried using `.Where(p => p.cProcedureName == HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(procedureName))` as well as `.Where(p => p.cProcedureName == Uri.EscapeDataString(procedureName))` both of which avoid the exception, but neither query finds the matching record in the database.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you change your `web.config` as per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147)?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for this simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the article referenced by NetMage in the comments above, simply adding the following setting to `web.config` on the server resolved this issue:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147